# parse YAML with line numbers for all keys

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I want to parse a YAML file structured as follows:

```
key1:
    key2: 10
    key3:
        key4:
            key5:
                "value1"
                "value2"
```

For now, I use the following code:

```
data = yaml.load(file, Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
print(data['key1'].lc.line) #I get line number of key1
print(data['key1']['key3'].lc.line) #I get line number of key3
print(data['key1']['key3']['key4'].lc.line) #I get line number of key4
```

Now I can't get line numbers for `key2` and `key5`. I figured out that the issue is due to the fact that `data[key][key2]` is not a dictionary, it is rather an `int`. Similarly, `data[key1][key3][key4][key5]` is a list not a dictionary.

Is there a way to get line numbers for **all** keys in this case?

Comment: Your code is incomplete without the import statements, your YAML is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
key1:
  key2: 10
  key3:
    key4:
      key5:
        - "value1"
        - "value2"
      key6: 20
      key7:
        key8:
          - "value3"
          - "value4"
```

```py
import yaml

with open('test.yml') as f:
    data = yaml.full_load(f)

result = {}
current = 1


def keyId(val, current):
    ks = val.keys()
    for key in ks:
        result[key] = current
        current += 1
        if isinstance(val[key], type([])):
            current += len(val[key])
        if isinstance(val[key], type({})):
            keyId(val[key], current)

    return


keyId(data, current)
print(result)
```

```
{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3, 'key4': 4, 'key5': 5, 'key6': 8, 'key7': 9, 'key8': 10}
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is an issue as soon as there is an empty line in the yaml file, for example between key6 and key7. Also, your code didn't work for me before I loaded the file using : `data = yaml.load(f, Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)`

Comment: @Mayank `ruamel.yaml`, doesn't have a `full_load()` function. You seem to be usng PyYAML, without indicating that the OP would need to downgrade his (real) input to YAML 1.1, replaced in 2009. And the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since 2006. Welcome to the twenties!

Comment: @fatiha.kafou to address the issue with empty lines, you can take this approach.. 1st get all keys from your yaml file.. store the keys in order you get them in an array.. then read the yaml as text and read line by line to get exact line number.

Comment: @fatiha.kafou I have added an another answer to do want you want to do and also accounting for line breaks

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong at multiple levels:

- You are using the old `ruamel.yaml` interface and have both `yaml.` and `ruamel.yaml` in your code. 
  Are you using the RoundTripLoader with PyYAML?
- Your input is not valid YAML, as you cannot have a double quoted
  scalar (`"value1"`) followed by another (you can of course in
  Python). Since you talk about "is a list", but there is no sequence
  in the input that would create a list, you probably have left out
  dashes.
- You confuse the numbers that you get with line numbers for the keys
  in your various mappings.  Although it might be difficult to see
  that counting starts at 0, it is obvious if you put in an extra
  (empty) line in the input
- It is perfectly possible to print
  `data['key1']['key3']['key4']['key5'].lc.line`, as that value is a
  list (subtype) although this is of course the line number for the start of that list
  not for `key5`
- Since `data['key1']['key2']` is an `int`, I don't understand how you
  can expect an attribute indicating a line number on that type (for
  itself or some key if that `int` happens to be a dict value).  Have
  you ever tried to set an attribute on a built-in class like `int`?
  Try `10.lc = 24` sometime.

```
import ruamel.yaml 

yaml_str = """\
key1:
    key2: 10
    key3:

        key4:
            key5:
                - "value1"
                - "value2"
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
assert isinstance(data['key1']['key2'], int)
print(data['key1'].lc.line) # the starting line number of the value associated with of key1
print(data['key1']['key3'].lc.line) # the starting line number of the value associated with key3
print(data['key1']['key3']['key4'].lc.line) # the starting line number of the value of key4
print(data['key1']['key3']['key4']['key5'].lc.line) # the starting line number of the value of key5
```

which gives:

```
1
4
5
6
```

Because of the extra line in the input, the output changes from `1 3 4 5` to `1 4 5 6` 
and it should be clear
that what you are not getting are not line numbers for any of the keys.

So it should be obvious, you are not getting line numbers for keys **at all**.

Yes, there is a way to get line numbers for all keys.
(In case you realise you wanted to know how to do that: you should take that information from all the `key_node` assignments in the method `construct_mapping` of the
`RoundTripLoader` class (it is subclass that and provide it to the
`yaml` instance before loading) and attach it to some attribute of
your own in the `maptyp` variable of that method.)

Answer (score 0):

```
key1:
  key4: 10
  key3:
    key8:

      key5:
        - "value1"
        - "value2"
      key6: 20
      key7:

        key2:
          - "value3"
          - "value4"
```

```py
with open('test.yml') as f:
    lines = list(map(lambda x: x.strip().split(':')[0] if x.find(':') != -1 else "", f.readlines()))
    print(lines)
```

```
['key1', 'key4', 'key3', 'key8', '', 'key5', '', '', 'key6', 'key7', '', 'key2', '', '']
```

Here each key is stored at index of its occurrence in yml file

Comment: A YAML file can have multiple keys on one line. A scalar can have a colon embedded. Your code cannot deal with either.

Comment: Another issue with this code is that it cannot differentiate between two keys with the same name.